# Android Studio preferences screen not responding/crashing when the menu item 'settings' is clicked

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I've tried to set up a class called preferences and then have the main activity change to the preferences class when the settings button is clicked :
[http://i.imgur.com/GE5WcUv.png](https://i.imgur.com/GE5WcUv.png) (not enough reputation to post image)

My main activity code to link to the preferences class is this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem v) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

Intent openAboutActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            Preferences.class);
    startActivity(openAboutActivityIntent);
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(v);
}
```

My android manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".Preferences"
        android:label="@string/set_preferences">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>

</application>
```

My error message :

```
02-09 14:38:02.540 13801-13801/com.example.co5025.assignement01
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
02-09 14:38:02.541 13801-13801/com.example.co5025.assignement01
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback

02-09 14:38:02.543 13801-13801/com.example.co5025.assignement01 
E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable
 to find explicit activity class 
{com.example.co5025.assignement01/java.util.prefs.Preferences}; have
 you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

My main Activity imports:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;
```

Also my Intent import is Yellow as are all the uses of the Intent in the main activity.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? Your `java.util.prefs.Preferences` activity cannot be found, and I don't see you declaring it as such in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Looks like your import is wrong. Can you post your Preferences class and your imports in your MainActivity class?

Comment: Yeah the preferences class is defined in the same package Raymond  and i dont have a java.util.prefs.Preferences activity, i have created a blank activity called Preferences.